# how to use a variable in parameters

Tags: string, variables, c++-cli

i need to know how to use a variable in parameters
PROCESS is initalized as
`string PROCESS` in the class parameters.

```
Process::GetProcessesByName("")
```

which gives me an error when i replace the string with a variable

```
Process::GetProcessesByName(PROCESS)
```

The error i get back is:
No instance of overloaded function "System::Diagnostics::Process::GetProcessByName" Matches the argument list argument types are (std::string)

Comment: I am using namespace System::Diagnostics;

Comment: Is this C++ for .NET? Is Process a std::string or a System::String?

Comment: C++ and process is a std::string

Comment: What's the declaration of `GetProcessByName`?

Comment: for each (Process^ process in Process::GetProcessesByName(PROCESS)){

Comment: That's also not the declaration of `GetProcessByName`

Comment: yes o am doing it with CLI which i didnt think made much of a difference? and i looked up the getprocessbyname public:
static array<Process^>^ GetProcessesByName(
 String^ processName
)

Comment: So the datatype uses a handle ^ how can i make the variable a handle aswell?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: @RichardGrant: Yes, it makes a huge difference.

Comment: well i will look up later i only made it cli because i needed to include a dll for system diagnostics. any idea how to get the datatype as string^?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `GetProcessesByName` may take a parameter as `LPSTR` or `char const *`, but not a `std::string`,

try use

```
Process::GetProcessesByName(PROCESS.c_str());
```

or if your PROCESS is defined as `std::string PROCESS;`,

```
   String^ process_name = gcnew String(PROCESS.c_str());
   Process::GetProcessesByName(process_name);
```

Comment: "System::Diagnostics::Process::GetProcessByName" Matches the argument list argument types are (const char *)

Comment: If it needs a `char const *`, then `std::string::c_str()` should work.

Comment: Try `Process::GetProcessesByName(PROCESS.c_str());` . If it does not work, what's error message?

Comment: the error is "System::Diagnostics::Process::GetProcessByName" Matches the argument list argument types are (const char *)

Comment: The paramater takes datatype of string^ according to msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: @RichardGrant You seem to be lacking in absolute basics. You should consider following a beginners' tutorial or a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If i am lacking in absolute basics then you should be able to answer the question rather then being pompous.

Comment: to get a `System::String^` from `std::string`, try    `string str = "test";  String^ str2 = gcnew String(str.c_str());`

Comment: I think your on the right track but its giving me an error system::String str2^ expression must have a class type

Comment: @RichardGrant Sorry, I didn't mean to sound offensive (or pompous). But I do believe that at basic level, a good tutorial or book provides better learning material than separate questions about individual problems.